# django forms use multiple widget for field

Tags: django, forms, widget, field

I would like to use multiple widgets on 1 form field in django.

```
password = forms.CharField(required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password:'}))
```

When I use it like this, i get the error: "keyword argument repeated "
I understand that I am using widget= twice, but I cant figure out how else to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PasswordInput extends TextInputt so you can simply do it like this:

```
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password:'}))
```

Comment: Thanks this work. Now im wondering if this is always the case, or are there moments you actual need to split the widgets up?

Comment: You can only use one widget per field. In most cases you will use built-in widgets, but if they won't suit your needs you can always write your own - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: Actually, he can pack multiple widgets into one thanks to MultiWidget class and use the bundle https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget

Comment: Thank you so much @KamilRykowski It really helped me too